# Why is reassigning Object.prototype not working?

Tags: javascript, syntax, function, prototype, object

Why this is not working?

```
// this one works as I expected, when objSayHello()
Object.prototype.objSayHello = function(){alert('Hello,from OBJECT prototype')};
// NOT working !
Object.prototype ={objSayHello: function(){alert('Hello,from OBJECT prototype')}};

objSayHello();
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Because you've replaced the `Object` prototype, so you're adding a `objSayHello` method to any object descending from `Object` (all objects).
2. Don't replace `Object.prototype`.

What you probably want is:

```
someObj.prototype.objSayHello = function(){alert('Hello,from OBJECT prototype')};
```

Then to call it with:

```
someObj.objSayHello();
```

What you seem to be meaning to do is:

```
Object.prototype.objSayHello = function(){alert('Hello,from OBJECT prototype')};
```

But that is probably a bad idea as it will conflict with iterators (`for...in`) if not handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Object.prototype is for some reason a const, which means read only.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.prototype.objSayHello = function(to){alert('Hello, ' + to)};
```

The above statement means that you attached the `objSayHello` function to all the instances that will be created as every instance is child of `Object` so the attached event bind to all. For instance,

```
var newObject = {};
var anotherNewObject = new Object();

function person(name) {
 this.name = name;
}
var newPerson = new Person("Ramiz");

newObject.objSayHello("newObject");
anotherNewObject.objSayHello("anotherNewObject");
newPerson.objSayHello(this.name);
```

While, the other statement is incorrect and will be ignored completely as you're about to discard the `prototype` of an object which is parent of all. If the `prototype` of `Object` can be override then all native instances functionality will be gone. To avoid such a mistake I think this is ignore to be override.

Answer (score 1):

Eyelidlessness is wrong, you simply [can't reassign the prototypes of intrinsic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5s9ycex%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) like Object, Number, etc. You can only append new properties.

```
> Number.prototype
  -> Number
> Number.prototype = {}  // Reassignment fails
  -> Object
> Number.prototype
  -> Number
> Number.prototype.objSayHello = 'hi'  // Appending succeeds
  -> 'hi'
> n = new Number(); n.objSayHello
  -> 'hi'
```

If you are using your own objects, then you can update or reassign the prototype (note: reassigning the prototype will only affect new objects, not existing ones).

**Do not change intrisic prototypes!** This is a 'bad thing' because it can cause hard-to-find side effects. If you need a basic type with new properties, then create a new object with the prototype pointing to the basic object:

```
NewObject = function() {};
NewObject.prototype = Object.prototype;
NewObject.prototype.value = 123;
```

Now you have a constructor that creates new objects that inherit properties from both its own prototype (eg 'value') as well as the Object prototype ('toString', 'hasOwnProperty'...).

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript language specification has this for [`Object.prototype`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype):

> The initial value of **Object.prototype** is %Object.prototype%.
>
> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: **false**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false** }.

You'll find the same "[[Writable]]: **false**" specification for the `prototype` properties of all other native JavaScript constructors, such as `Function`, `Number`, `RegExp`, `Date`, ...etc.

Answer (score -1):

Object.prototype isn't actually the real prototype, it's only a reference. An internal [[prototype]] object is used as prototype, and it's accessible in some browsers as **proto** property of an object. Given the way JavaScript variables work, assigning the Object.prototype to another object changes it's reference but without changing internal [[prototype]] object, thus you get an normal property called prototype which says nothing about how object properties are resolved.

So, why does this work when you do Object.prototype.myFunction() ? The Object.prototype is still a **reference** to the internal [[prototype]] so it has no problem with augmenting it with this function, it works as with any other objects.